# Change week start day on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, time, calendar

I googled this and tried many different results. Not one of them works. I can't find anything up-to-date as most solutions are for older versions of Ubuntu. Can anyone tell me how I can change the start day of the week from Sunday to Monday in the Ubuntu calender? This thing is really bugging me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this depends on the locale. I have set my locale under System  settings --> language support --> Regional formats to Greek and the week begins on Monday.

Comment: @Bruni yes it worked. Thanks a lot! You can post this in the answer and I will select it as the chosen answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the locale. E.g I have set my locale under System settings --> language support --> Regional formats to Greek and the week begins on Monday